# How do I nest look-behind assertions if there is text in between?

Tags: objective-c, regex, json, screen-scraping

I'm trying to use regex to match text that has certain words preceding it (the words "slide" and "title" in this case). I've been trying to use look-behind assertions and nesting them within one another but it doesn't seem to be working. The other problem is that there is some other text in between the "slide" and "title" words that I'm using to match.

I've tried:

```
(?<=slide(?<=title\\s=\\s)).*(?=\\\")
(?<=title\\s=\\s(?<=slide)).*(?=\\\")
```

Any suggestions as to how to do this? Extra slashes are for escaping; I'm using this in objective-c but I don't know if that matters much.

A part of the JSON I'm scraping for better context (I'm looking to get the title after "title" in each slide):

```
slide =                 {
                createdAt = "2013-06-18T20:06:50Z";
                description = "<p>Due to the amount of attention paid to each organization's top prospects and early-round draft picks, many of the game's underrated prospects are perpetually obscured. Most of the time, these prospects are younger players who are housed in the low minors and still require considerable physical projection. At the same time, there are countless prospects on the older side of the age curve who have dipped off the radar due to injury.</p><p>Here's a look at one \"hidden gem\" from each organization who could make a push for the major leagues in the coming years.</p>";
                embedCode = "";
                externalId = "<null>";
                id = 3219926;
                photoHasCropExact = 1;
                photoHasCropNorth = 0;
                primaryPhoto =                     {
                    url = "http://img.bleacherreport.net/img/slides/photos/003/219/926/hi-res-5382332_crop_north.jpg";
                };
                title = "Each MLB Team's 'Hidden Gem' Prospect Fans May Not Know About";
                updatedAt = "2013-06-18T22:26:30Z";
                url = "<null>";
```

Comment: Do you want to parse JSON with regular expressions? A proper JSON parser such as NSJSONSerialization would be a better solution. And btw. what you have shown in your question is not JSON. - Perhaps you can better explain what you *really* want to achieve.

Comment: Fixed it thanks a lot. Just ended up using NSJSONSerialization instead thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @MartinR on this one, but to answer the *regex* question, it's because you're indeed specifying an impossible condition. What you *mean* is

```
(?<=(?<=title\\s=\\s)slide).*(?=\\\")
(?<=(?<=slide)title\\s=\\s).*(?=\\\")
```

To see why, consider the following regex:

```
(?<=foo(?<=bar)).
```

You are looking for a character that is preceded by "foo" *and* preceded by "bar". Why, of course, since "foo" and "bar" are never the same, that condition can never match. If you want "bar" to precede "foo", then you have to do it this way:

```
(?<=(?<=bar)foo).
```

Also, keep in mind that in most cases, regular expressions engines don't support variable-width lookbehinds. Your examples only contain fixed-width lookbehinds, but in case your actual implementation is more complex, that may be another reason your regexes arne't working.